# Android Device screen not turning off

Tags: android, android-activity, android-wake-lock, display

I started songs on one of the music apps, on my android device.

Although I can see only partial wake_locks being acquired, still device display doesn't turn off even after screen timeout.

I wonder what is keeping the device screen on.

Can someone suggest where to look for probable cause.

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide some code. How are you aquiring the wake locks, what does your manifest look like, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
    pm.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My wakelook");
// This will make the screen and power stay on
// This will release the wakelook after 1000 ms
wakeLock.acquire(1000);

// Alternative you can request and / or  release the wakelook via:
// wakeLock.acquire(); wakeLock.release();
```

I used this code and works fine to me.